# How to change text on a label on a specific row

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a piece of code where I make labels and buttons on a loop until I have enough to fit all the data, now I am trying to change the text in label 3 (lbl3) with a click of a button in the same row.

- So the first thing I had to do was to get the row it was on which I have and the column which I know.
- Now I am trying to change the text of the label but they are all named the same because off the way they are created, so is there any way to change to change the text on a specific row? like with **.configure** and you specify the **row** and **column**.
  This is some of the code i have, here I get the index of the button and also the label with `i` (the last one)

```py
btn_unblur_pass = Button(frame_inside, text="U", command=partial(unblurPassword, array[i][0], i))
```

The following code is where I do some stuff with the database and set the label to that but this is where I need to be able to specify the row of this label because they are created with a loop.

```
def unblurPassword(input, index):
    cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM vault WHERE id = ?", (input,))
    array1 = cursor.fetchall()
    pass_txt_unblur = decrypt(array1[0][0], encryptionKey)
    row = index + 3
    column = 2

    lbl3.configure(text=pass_txt_unblur)

    btn_unblur_pass.configure(command=partial(blurPassword, array[i][0], i))

def blurPassword(input, index):
    cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM vault WHERE id = ?", (input,))
    array2 = cursor.fetchall()
    pass_txt1 = decrypt(array2[0][0], encryptionKey)
    pass_len1 = len(pass_txt1)
    pass_star1 = pass_len1 * "*"
    row = index + 3
    column = 2

    lbl3.configure(text=pass_star1)

    btn_unblur_pass.configure(command=partial(unblurPassword, array[i][0], i))
```

Here is the code that makes the label and button :

````py
i = 0
        while True:
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
            array = cursor.fetchall()

            if (len(array) == 0):
                break

            pass_txt = decrypt(array[i][3], encryptionKey)
            pass_len = len(pass_txt)
            pass_star = pass_len * "*"

            lbl1 = Label(frame_inside, text=(decrypt(array[i][1], encryptionKey)), font=("Helvetica", 12))
            lbl1.grid(column=0, row=(i + 3))
            lbl2 = Label(frame_inside, text=(decrypt(array[i][2], encryptionKey)), font=("Helvetica", 12))
            lbl2.grid(column=1, row=(i + 3))
            lbl3 = Label(frame_inside, text=pass_star, font=("Helvetica", 12))
            lbl3.grid(column=2, row=(i + 3))
```python
btn_unblur_pass = Button(frame_inside, text="U", command=partial(unblurPassword, array[i][0], i))
            btn_unblur_pass.grid(column=4, row=(i + 3), pady=10)

i = i + 1

            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
            if (len(cursor.fetchall()) <= i):
                break
````

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried so far. It's very difficult to help without knowing where you're at.

Comment: Better provide a [mre].  Your posted code has undefined variables like `i` and `array`.  Also `array2[i][3]` has invalid index `3` as the returned SQL result has only one item in each record.  Moreover it is not clear which *label* you want to update its text based on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the password label and blur/unblur button to the two functions instead of *record ID* and *index*, then you don't need to know the row and column where the label is and don't need to execute any SQL query inside the functions.

Below is an simplified example based on your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def unblur_password(lbl, btn):
    lbl.config(text=lbl.passwd) # show the password
    btn.config(text='Blur', command=partial(blur_password, lbl, btn))

def blur_password(lbl, btn):
    lbl.config(text='*'*len(lbl.passwd)) # hide the password
    btn.config(text='Unblur', command=partial(unblur_password, lbl, btn))

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(padx=10, pady=10)

# sample data from "SELECT * FROM vault"
result = [
    (1, 'first', 'record', 'hello1234'),
    (2, 'second', 'record', 'world5678')
]

fnt = 'Helvetica 12'
for i, rec in enumerate(result, 3):
    tk.Label(root, text=rec[1], font=fnt, width=len(rec[1])).grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5)
    tk.Label(root, text=rec[2], font=fnt, width=len(rec[2])).grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5)

    pass_len = len(rec[3])
    lbl_passwd = tk.Label(root, text='*'*pass_len, width=pass_len, font=fnt)
    lbl_passwd.grid(row=i, column=2, padx=5)
    lbl_passwd.passwd = rec[3]  # store the password in an attribute of label

    btn_toggle = tk.Button(root, text='Unblur', width=10)
    btn_toggle.config(command=partial(unblur_password, lbl_passwd, btn_toggle))
    btn_toggle.grid(row=i, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot this indeed works and it is surprisingly simple.

Comment: @KelvinHollander If it solves your problem, consider to accept it as the answer by clicking the `tick` beside the answer.